# Python Module for SMBIOS

Tags: python, linux, windows, bios

I am looking for a Python module that wraps [SMBIOS](http://www.dmtf.org/standards/smbios).
If there is none such; do you have any advice on the best way to parse system memory in Python to find the SMBIOS table.

There is [information available about how to recognize the table in memory](http://wiki.osdev.org/System_Management_BIOS), assuming you can parse memory. I have never tried to parse arbitrary memory in Python; I am sure there would be some issues with access rights...

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Hoping for a solution that abstracts that and works with Windows and Linux. Will test on my Windows machine.

Comment: This appears to be linux-only: http://linux.dell.com/libsmbios/download/libsmbios/ , http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid-updates/libsmbios-dev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of anything ready-made.

On Windows, my best suggestion is to use ctypes and load the kernel32 library. See the GetSystemFirmwareTable function. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724379

> The raw SMBIOS table provider ('RSMB') retrieves the contents of the raw SMBIOS firmware table.

You would then need to write a class to parse the data.

I don't know about Linux, but I suspect there is something similar to retrieve the SMBIOS table.